# Error SIGABRT while trying to delete multiple selected cells in UICollectionView:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sigabrt

I am trying to delete a series of selected images in a `UICollectionView` on clicking the Delete button. Here is my Delete Button action:

```
- (IBAction)deleteVideos:(id)sender {
    if(deleteEnabled){
        if([selectedVideos count]>0){
            for(NSArray *indexPath in self.memoryMirrorSessionCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems) {
                [videoImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
                [image_array removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath];
                NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
                [self.memoryMirrorSessionCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPath];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And these are my declarations and definitions:

```
@interface XVZUICollectionController(){
    NSMutableArray *videoImagesArray;
    BOOL selectEnabled;
    NSMutableArray *selectedVideos;
    BOOL deleteEnabled;
    BOOL shareEnabled;
    NSInteger *indexStack;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    image_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:     @"TestImage1.jpg", @"TestImage2.png", @"TestImage3.jpg", @"TestImage4.png",@"TestImage5.jpg", @"TestImage2.png",@"TestImage1.jpg", @"TestImage5.jpg", nil ];
    videoImagesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: image_array, nil];   
}
```

When I click on the delete button, i get a signal abort exception on the highlighted line below. Any suggestions?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        **return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([NMAppDelegate class]));** //SIGABRT
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide details about the crash. Also, see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is structured incorrectly.

You are repeatedly retrieving an `NSArray` reference but then using this as an integer in your delete calls.

You should retrieve the selected index paths once and then iterate over the selected paths -

```
- (IBAction)deleteVideos:(id)sender {
    if(deleteEnabled){
        if([selectedVideos count]>0){
            NSArray *selectedIndexPaths=self.memoryMirrorSessionCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;
            for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
                [videoImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
                [image_array removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath,item];
                NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.item);
                [self.memoryMirrorSessionCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPath];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im still getting the sigabrt exception.. and on adding a breakpoint.. its aborting at NSArray *selectedIndexPaths=self.memoryMirrorSessionCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems; . Is there anyway I can look to know more on why this is crashing?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on this line and check that `self.memoryMirrorSessionCollectionView` is valid.  Also try setting an exception breakpoint.

Comment: I think PS1690 has structured the for loop correctly. This for loop called fast enumeration which is confirms to NSFastEnumeration protocol which call the function once. Generally sigabrt exception comes when you access n + 1 element from an array which has only n elements.

Comment: `indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns an NSArray of NSIndexPath, so you can use fast enumeration, but the each iteration of the enumeration is going to return `NSIndexPath *` not `NSArray *`.  I simply split the retrieving of the array out of the loop for clarity.  Accessing beyond the end of the array will give an array out of bounds exception, but that won't occur here because enumeration is in use, not a simple counting loop